# sql server returns The underlying provider failed on Open. in parallel foreach

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, parallel-processing

I have some entities which i want read them from SQLServer using Parallel foreach .

```
Parallel.ForEach<PersonCalculation>(people, (person) =>
        {
            using (PayrollContext _context = new PayrollContext(SainaLibrary.Basic.Configure.GetConnectionString("Payroll")))
            {
                if (_context.PayrollHistories.Any(p => p.PayPersonRef == person.PayPersonId &&
                                                       p.Year == year &&
                                                       p.Month == month &&
                                                       p.CalculationType == (byte)calculationType))
                    _peopleName.Add(person.FullName);
            }
        });
```

when i connecting to sql server using windows authentication, every things works good, but when i connecting to sql server using "SA" user, sql server returns "The underlying provider failed on Open." error. and the inner exception is "Login failed for user 'sa'."

how can i fix it ?

Comment: How did you configure the server / database? (you can configure it to use windows authentication, or sql authentication or a mix)

Comment: is it the correct password for the user SA?

Comment: your title says that the problem is local to parallel foreach. Does that mean, if you run it outside `Parallel.ForEach` it works?

Comment: also, see this: ["Login failed for user" error message when you log on to SQL Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/555332?wa=wsignin1.0) which is the first hit on that error message on google.

Comment: the password for SA user is correct and the server configured to Mixed Mode. also when i run my codes outside "Parallel.foreach" it works